# How to use Fourier's transform to solve differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have to solve following problem:

$$ u_t(t,x) = \Delta u(t,x) $$
$$ u(0,x) = f(x) $$

I've started:

$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta t} F(u(t,\xi))=F(u_t(t,\xi))=F(\Delta u(t,x))$$

and here I've stoped, because what I also know is:

$$ \frac{\delta^2u}{\delta x_k^2}=(i\xi_k)^2F(u) $$

Unfortunatelly here I've got $$ \Delta u(t,x) $$ not $$ \Delta_x u(t,x) $$

Could someone help me what should I do in the next step?

Comment: That equation seems to be the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation). Usually, symbol $\Delta$ is used to express the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) only for space variables. Can you check that?

Comment: **Hint:** For the 1-D case, and using the $e^{-2 \pi i \xi x}$ notation

\begin{align}
\hat u(x,t) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} u(x,t) e^{-2 \pi i \xi x} dx \\
\implies \hat u_{t}(x,t) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_{t}(x,t) e^{-2 \pi i \xi x} dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_{xx}(x,t) e^{-2 \pi i \xi x} dx
\end{align}

then integrate by parts on $x$ to get the desired ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 2:
use a test function $e^{i(\omega t-k x)}$ and see what the differential operators do in this function.

Then the (whole) Fourier solution is the (function represented by the) sum over all these (fourier basis) functions.

In other words if the required solution is expanded in a 2-D fourier space of the above basis functions:

$$f(x,t) = \sum_k \sum_{\omega} c_{\omega k} \times e^{i(\omega t - k x)}$$

One needs only solve the diff. equation for each $e^{i(\omega t - k x)}$ and combine. (note the sums above are formal, they may represent integrals if needed)

In most cases of linear partial differential equations this also leads to a *separation of parameters* solution, where the equation is split into loosely-coupled parts each related to one parameter (i.e $x$ or $t$)